# Save multiple Selected Items From List box In Access

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

I have a simple form in Microsoft Access 2010 in which I have a list box with Multi-Select Enabled. I want to save the selected items in table. How would I go about it in Access 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multi-select listbox has an `ItemsSelected` collection, which you can loop through using a `For..Each` loop. From the Help page:

> Use the ItemsSelected collection in conjunction with the Column
>   property or the ItemData property to retrieve data from selected rows
>   in a list box or combo box. You can list the ItemsSelected collection
>   by using the For Each...Next statement.

Click on the word `ItemsSelected` and press F1 to get into the Help system.

You might then use DAO (or ADO) to create a `RecordSet` and use the `AddNew` to insert the selected items.